# Raspberrypi3 system calls - passing 64 bit arguments

Tags: assembly, linux-kernel, arm, system-calls, raspberry-pi3

I created a system call for my raspberrypi3 in the kernel from github.com/raspberrypi/linux and with the RT patch applied.

Upon playing around, I notice I can't pass a 64 bit argument.  I created a user app that uses the syscall() function for testing.

Here is my system call:

```
asmlinkage long sys_testCall(const char __user* buf, unsigned long long testVal)
{
    unsigned long long val1 = 1000;
    unsigned long long val2 = 68719476735;
    unsigned long long retVal = 0;

    retVal = val1 + val1;
    printk("sum 1000 = %llu\n", retVal);

    retVal = val2 + val2;
    printk("sum Fs = %llu\n", retVal);

    printk("DEBUG: Entering %s %d \n", __FUNCTION__, __LINE__);
    printk("DEBUG: Buff: %s\n", buf);
    printk("DEBUG: testVal: %llu\n", testVal);
    printk("DEBUG: testVal: %llx\n", testVal);

    return 0;
}
```

and here is my user app:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

// arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -o sysTest userSyscallTest.c

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int val = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

    unsigned long long testVal = 100;
    char *mess = "MyMessage";

    printf("SYSCALL TEST: %d\n", val);
    if (397 == val)
    {
        long int test_call_ret = syscall(val, mess, testVal);
    }
    else
    {
        long int syscallRet = syscall(val);
    }
}
```

I compile on the target and execute ./sysTest 397 ... with that, I get:

```
SYSCALL TEST: 397[  595.650294] sum 1000 = 2000

[  595.654537] sum Fs = 137438953470
[  595.658007] DEBUG: Entering sys_testCall 53
[  595.662279] DEBUG: Buff: MyMessage
[  595.665682] DEBUG: testVal: 9137185598140841984
[  595.670214] DEBUG: testVal: 7ecdcde400000000
```

I'm not sure how to explain how the "math" handles 64bit values while the system call does not.  I assume both conditions are handled from some register loads, moves, swaps, etc.  But, I am not sure of those details.  *I'm currently looking ...*

While I continue searching through my code, I figured I would ask here as well.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you running 32 bit or 64 bit Linux?

Comment: `I assume both conditions are handled from some register loads, moves, swaps` - No, you are wrong. Syscalls doesn't obey for ABI, which regulates passing parameters to normal functions.

Comment: @fuz 32bit.  I originally started with code that successfully ran on x86.  Upon porting it to my rpi3, I noticed certain system calls with 64 bit arguments failing.  I created the one above, along with a simple application for testing, and discovered the same result.

Comment: @DavidNorwood Did your code ran on 32 bit x86 or 64 bit x86? I'm asking because you can't directly pass 64 bit arguments to system calls on 32 bit platforms, you have to split the argument up into two 32 bit arguments IIRC.  Look at system calls like `_llseek` to find out what needs to be done.

Comment: @fuz I anticipate breaking the 64bit arguments into 32bits will solve my problem (_making changes to those right now_), at least insofar as passing things through system calls.  My understanding is that my original x86 based code was 32bit as well, and functional, however in an emulated environment.  With that, I suppose the emulator masked the problems I'm seeing on actual hardware.

Comment: @fuz yes, breaking the 64bit argument into two 32bit arguments worked.  Ugh.  Now I have to find who is using these calls and break/piece together ecah 64bit value.  Fun times :)  Thanks.

Comment: @DavidNorwood I know this is unelegant, that's why you shouldn't make new system calls if there are better ways (such as adding a new `ioctl`).